# How can I automate the following web browsing using python?

Tags: python

How can I automate the following web browsing using python?

1. go to certain url
2. click on some buttons

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Thanks for editing my question. I am hoping that you will guide me better.

Comment: ... I don't understand why you would need to perform this download more than once?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel this is just an example, i have to repeat for other many files...

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I have asked a new question please have a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185301/automate-web-browsing-using-python#21185301

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I have asked a new question please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185301/automate-web-browsing-using-python#21185301

Comment: @viena: there is no need to ping people in comments; if you asked a clear, complete question following the [guidelines for good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then your question will receive plenty of attention.

Answer (score 3):

You can consider leveraging Selenium.

Here is some information:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium

[How to use Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python)

Comment: I have asked a new question please have a lookhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/21185301/automate-web-browsing-using-python#21185301