# automate web browsing using python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('http://www.example.com')
```

Then, how can I click on the third Download button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a xpath expresion to get all inputs with a "Download" value, and click the third:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@value="Download"]')[2].click()
```

Comment: thank you so much. You may be interested in my next question too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python  @Krzysztof Rosiński