# Fill username and password using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

How can I auto fill the username and password over the link below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
browser.get('http://www.example.com')
```

After that I really do not know:

```
username = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('Username'))
password = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('Password'))
username.select_by_visible_text("text")
password.select_by_visible_text("text")
```

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Docs: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html

For versions 4.3.0 (released in June 2022) and later, calls to `find_element_by_*` and `find_elements_by_*` were removed from Selenium. You need to use the new API:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox(...)  # Or Chrome(), or Ie(), or Opera()

# To catch <input type="text" id="passwd" />
password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwd")
# To catch <input type="text" name="passwd" />
password = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "passwd")

password.send_keys("Pa55worD")

driver.find_element(By.NAME, "submit").click()
```

The original response, for API versions 4.2.0 or previous:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(...)  # Or Chrome(), or Ie(), or Opera()

username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("YourUsername")
password.send_keys("Pa55worD")

driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

A note to your code: `Select()` is used to act on a Select Element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select).

Comment: Hey, do you know how to read the contents of the page that's loaded after submitting the form? I am writing a test for a website, and I managed to submit the form, and now I am lost. In other words, I want to get the contents of the restricted, members only landing page.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac The "selenium" object works like a browser. Once you "click" it loads the new landing page, so you can do 'selenium.find_element_by_id("whatever")'. Read also about "selenium.implicitly_wait()" to wait between page loads.

Comment: Note, in the above answer, selenium should be the driver handle obtained, for example, selenium = webdriver.Firefox()

Comment: @xbello Thank you very much!

Comment: This answer is outdated after the 2022 API changes.  See answer above by @haritha_kh for the corrections ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python/71814183#71814183 )

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD you can edit answers if they are wrong/outdated.

Comment: @xbello, do you know why sometimes the ID of the html element for the password textbox is sometimes "password" and sometimes it would be "Passwd", the reason my login automation fails on this part: <<password = driver.find_element(By.ID, "passwd")>>

Comment: @toking it's up the web developer. It could be "password", "passwd", a random string, or even have no name nor id attributes. You have to view the page source code and find what you want. Usually forms are generated by frameworks, and they default to name="password" or id="password".

Comment: @xbello thank you very much for your brilliant reply. Unfortunately { driver.find_element(By.NAME, "submit").click() } on my desired url returns the following error message elenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [name="submit"]. How should I parse the html page to understand what fields the login page requires.

Comment: @Andreuccio, manually you have to right-click on the button that does the submit, and click "inspect". A window opens, where you have to find the button you want to "click" and figure out a way to get it from the DOM (by Name, by Id, or by Css Selector / XPath as shown [here](https://github.com/xbello/wagtail-tag-manager.git) )

Answer (score 32):

Use [`WebElement.send_keys`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) method to simulate key typing.

`name` in the code (`Username`, `Password`) does not match actual `name` of the elements (`username`, `password`).

---

```
username = browser.find_element_by_name('username')
username.send_keys('user1')

password = browser.find_element_by_name('password')
password.send_keys('secret')

form = browser.find_element_by_id('loginForm')
form.submit()

# OR  browser.find_element_by_id('submit').click()
```

Comment: When I try this I get this error : 'StatefulBrowser' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_name'

Comment: @AnaClaudia, it is possible api changed since I posted this answer. Please check documentation.

Comment: This answer is outdated after the 2022 API changes.  See answer above by @haritha_kh for the corrections ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python/71814183#71814183 )

Answer (score 11):

```
user = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
user.clear()
user.send_keys("your_user_name")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("your_password")
driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
```

Note:

- we use`user.clear()` in order to clear the input field.
- for locating submit button you can use any other method based on the page source code. for info see [locating elements](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: This answer is outdated after the 2022 API changes.  See answer above by @haritha_kh for the corrections ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python/71814183#71814183 )

Answer (score 7):

In some cases when the element is not interactable, `sendKeys()` doesn't work and you're likely to encounter an `ElementNotInteractableException`.

In such cases, you can opt to execute javascript that sets the values and then can post back.

Example:

```py
url = 'https://www.your_url.com/'

driver = Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver")
driver.get(url)

username = 'your_username'
password = 'your_password'

#Setting the value of email input field
driver.execute_script(f'var element = document.getElementById("email"); element.value = "{username}";')

#Setting the value of password input field
driver.execute_script(f'var element = document.getElementById("password"); element.value = "{password}";')

#Submitting the form or click the login button also
driver.execute_script(f'document.getElementsByClassName("login_form")[0].submit();')

print(driver.page_source)
```

Reference:

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-resolve-the-ElementNotInteractableException-in-Selenium-WebDriver

Answer (score 2):

Here is the complete answer.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_driver_path = 'C:\\chromedriver.exe'
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chrome_driver_path))
browser.get('http://www.example.com')

username = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'Username')
password = browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'Password')

username.send_keys("yourUsername") #type your own username here
password.send_keys("yourPassword") #type your own password here

browser.find_element(By.NAME, 'submit').click()
```

Since `find_element_by_name()` is deprecated, you can use  `find_element(By.NAME, 'name')`.

Also you have to import  `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

Comment: This is a great answer in October 2022.  The find_element() function syntax changed.  This answer works pretty much "as is".  Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, you can use the command

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath()
```

For that, right-click on a button/field you interest (login,submit, username, password etc). After that **In Chrome** you choose [Inspect-> copy-> copy full xPath], while in **in Firefox** it be [Inspect-> copy-> XPath]. Now you do the following:

```
login_knob = driver.find_element_by_xpath("here you put code you copied for the push button").click()
username_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("here you put code you copied for the field username").send_keys('username')
password_field = driver.find_element_by_xpath("here you put code you copied for the field password").send_keys('password')
login_knob2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("here you put code you copied for the login button").click()
```

***Example of a copied code***

> /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

# If you want to open Chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# If you want to open Firefox
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
username.send_keys("YourUsername")
password.send_keys("YourPassword")
driver.find_element_by_id("submit_btn").click()
```

Comment: It worked to me, but I needed to use the "find_element_by_class" instead. And also add the Chrome driver path.

Comment: This answer is outdated after the 2022 API changes.  See answer above by @haritha_kh for the corrections ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python/71814183#71814183 )

Answer (score -1):

I am new to selenium and I tried all solutions above but they don't work.
Finally, I tried this manually by

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
import time

driver.get(url)

time.sleep(20)

print (driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
```

Then I could get contents from web.

Comment: solution is different as compared to question

Comment: If you need to wait for the page to load (a slow page response or connection), you should use https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.implicitly_wait . Your code waits for 20 seconds *always*. With implicitly_wait, if the page loads quickly you don't have to wait the whole 20 seconds. But is a different problem.