# Selenium fill in user name/pwd, only filling one field

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to do some web scraping and need to have selenium fill in login credentials, name and password.

I followed the directions here [Fill username and password using selenium in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python)

Here's my code:

```
username = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-username')
username.send_keys('bob')

password = driver.find_element_by_class_name('login-password')
password.send_keys('pop')

driver.find_element_by_id('login_checkbox').click()
driver.find_element_by_class_name('ok').click()
```

This works to get to the username but it won't move forward to the password. I end up with bobpop in the username field and, naturally, I can't move forward.

Please help me figure out how to make this happen!

Comment: It should be `driver.find_element_by_class_name`, is it a typo?

Comment: Perhaps adding an explicit wait would help.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages. Can i have site URL?

Comment: Can you share part of the HTML with the login form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of explicit localization of password element, it is often more practical something like this:

```
username.send_keys('bob' + Keys.TAB + 'pop' + Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: I had a feeling keys.tab would be part of it but couldn't get it to work correctly. This did the trick. Thanks so much!