# Use Existing Google Chrome Window To Web Scrape Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

Running Python 3.6 and I'm having a whole lot of issues logging to a site primarily due to captcha. I really only need to search up URLs and retrieve the html on the page but I need to be logged in for certain additional information to appear on the accessible URLs.

I was using urllib to read the URLs but now I was looking for a solution to login and then request information. The automatic route won't seem to work due to those issues, so I'm looking for a method by which I am already logged in on an open browser and python opens up new tabs to search for URLs (the searches can be hidden, they don't have to literally open up new tabs). It appears that when I open new tabs manually on the site it still shows i'm logged in so If i can manually log in each time i want to run the script and then work based off that, it would actually work just fine.

Thanks

Comment: IIUC, You can use selemium to enter text and submit the credentials. Use PhantomJS to mask opening and logging into the page. A related question is here: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python)

Comment: @Mokshyam I am not having an issue loginning on with selenium by entering credentials. The issue is with the captcha requests that I get every so often. There's not easy way to bypass the puzzles. I'm looking for a route where I can login via browser manually and then use the open browser to navigate webpages since I'll be logged in during my session.

Comment: I see what element holds the captcha. An iframe?