# Can't Fill Login Form with FormRequest in Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I use Python Scrapy and i try to connect to [this site](https://colruyt.collectandgo.be/cogo/fr/identifier).

I create a test account for this question

```
Email: g2387744@nwytg.com
password: 123456789
```

When I monitor the network during authentification 
[image]

I tried to fill the form with FormRequest

```
   data = {'loginName': 'g2387744@nwytg.com',
        'password' : '123456789',
        'rememberme' : 'true'
        }
    yield FormRequest("https://ecustomermw.colruytgroup.com/ecustomermw/v1/fr/customer/logon?client=cogo_cogo&variant=none" ,method="POST",formdata=data)
```

but I'm not logged in and I redirected to signup page

I read [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21186465/4527978) and I tried with Selenium

```
username = driver.find_element_by_id("loginName")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("password")

username.send_keys("g2387744@nwytg.com")
password.send_keys("123456789")

driver.find_elements_by_class_name("button.btn.large").click()
```

But I'm not logged in and I redirected to signup page

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Selenium code is almost correct. The problem is that authentication form located inside an iframe and you should switch to it to be able to handle inputs:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('iframe._loadEvent'))
driver.find_element_by_id('loginName').send_keys('g2387744@nwytg.com')
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('123456789')
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button[type="submit"]').click()
```