# How can I log in to this specific website / how can I use a cookie file to log in

Tags: python

My goal is to extract some information from the site every now and then automatically. To be able to do that I have to be logged in and I can't find a way to pass my credentials to the website.

```
import requests

EMAIL = 'randomemail@gmail.com'
PASSWORD = 'randompassword'
URL = 'https://www.myanonamouse.net'

def main():
    session = requests.Session()
    login_data = {
        'email': EMAIL,
        'password': PASSWORD,
        'submit': 'Log in!',
    }


    r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)
    print(r.text)
main()
```

I need some help fixing this part, but I would also like to know what I did wrong and how I can improve it (stay logged in for the entire session).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to use `selenium webdriver` for this.Just google and you will find tutorials. Meanwhile here is an example from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21186465/3091398)

Comment: If you want to start from what you have here, you need to use POST instead of GET. You’ll easily find tutorials on the web.

Comment: You should read the HTML of the site and see which method is used for authentication, which data should be passed, which URI should be accessed

Comment: @ForceBru I am not really sure at what I should look for. Could you link to me some stuff or write a small explanation? Thanks