# How to handle ezproxy authorization to download data through API?

Tags: python-3.x, url, request

I have a token to have an access to download large files from the comtrade. The original webpage is http://comtrade.un.org/ however I have a premium access through my university library subscription. So,[if I want to use the premium features the website automatically redirects me to this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W13Ha.png) and after pressing login button the URL is https://ezproxy.nu.edu.kz:5588/data/dev/portal/. I am trying to send request and download files with API(using requests). I am getting response from http://comtrade.un.org/ but in order to download I need to use https://ezproxy.nu.edu.kz:5588/data/dev/portal/. and when I tried to download:

> *urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized*

This error message appeared. How can I handle this problem?

```
px = 'px=HS&' #classification
freq = 'freq=A&' #annual
type = 'type=C&' #commodity
auth = 'https://comtrade.un.org/api/getUserInfo?token=ZF5TSW8giRQMFHuPmS5JwQLZ5FB%2BNO0NCcjxFQUJADrLzCRDCkG5F0ZPnZTYQWO3MPgj96gZNF7Z9iN8BwscUMYBbXuDVYVDvsTAVNzAJ6FNC2dnN7gtB1rt9qJShAO467zBegHTLwvmlRIBSpjjwg%3D%3D'




with open('reporterAreas.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

ls = data['results']

list_year = [*range(2011, 2021,1)]
for years in list_year:
    print(years)
    ps = 'ps='+ str(years) + '&'
    for item in ls:
        r = item['id']                              #report_country_id
        report_country_txt = item['text']
        if r == 'all':
            req_url = 'r=' + r + '&' + px + ps + type + freq + token
            request = url + req_url
            response = requests.get(request)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                print("Response is OK!")
            data = response.json()[0]
            download_url = dwld_url + data['downloadUri']
            print(download_url)
            filename = str(years) + '_' + report_country_txt + '.zip'
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if Ezproxy provides an API or SDK way to authenticate a request but i don't think.

What you could do is to provide the **Ezproxy session to your request** and with that, you request will not be treated as unauthorized because you're passing a valid session and therefore your request will be treated as a valid one.

Notice that you can retrieve your `Ezproxy session id` from your cookies.

[image]

And finally, you have to make your request against the [starting point url](https://help.oclc.org/Library_Management/EZproxy/EZproxy_configuration/Starting_point_URLs_and_config_txt)

[image]

---

Otherwise, you can use [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python) to fill automatically the login form and retrieve the `Ezproxy session id` to pass it to the requests.

I hope this could help you !