# I'm getting an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: attributes

I'm very new to Python, so I'm struggling a little getting this to work. I'm getting the error in the title, which from reading other threads, I'm guessing means it's returning a null value?

This is the code so far.

```
from openpyxl import workbook, load_workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://www.tax.service.gov.uk/check-vat-number/enter-vat-details"
html = requests.get(url)

s = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

results = s.find(id='ResultsContainer')
box = results.find_all('div', class_='govuk-width-container ')
```

Basically, I would like my programme to loop through the VAT checker, entering the VAT numbers from my spreadsheet, to determine whether they are valid or not. I got it to work using VBA, but I'm trying to do the same using Python.

The bit I'm stuck on is where the variable 'box' is supposed to equal the box id on the website, where users can enter their VAT number into. I hope I explained it correctly.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: There is no `ResultsContainer`  that is why you get the error while using a methode on `NoneType` - However, think your issue is another you have to perform a POST request with the VAT and a csrfToken as payload to get any result

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the code from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JlHdv4Dfjq4. I just adapted my code from theirs. I'm not advanced enough to understand your advice yet, but I'll work on it.

Comment: While working with `requests` check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733638/how-to-post-json-data-with-python-requests or while mimic a browser with `selenium` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python

Comment: What didn't occur to me at the beginning, is that when web scraping in this way, the actual web page doesn't open up, does it? In that way it's different than the VBA code I used before, where it physically opened up the web browser, and entered the VAT number into the box.