# python - using Selenium logging in

Tags: python, selenium, authentication

I followed the accepted answer's solution at:
[How to use Selenium with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python)

I am trying to log into coinbase https://coinbase.com/signin

Here is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


site = "https://coinbase.com/signin"
email = "myemail@mymail.com"
password = "mypassword"

xpaths = {
'emailTxtBox' : '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/input',      
'passwordTxtBox' : '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/div/input',
'submitButton' : '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/div/input'
    }

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(site)

#Write Username in Username TextBox
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['emailTxtBox']).send_keys(email)

#Write Password in password TextBox
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['passwordTxtBox']).send_keys(password)

#Click Login button
mydriver.find_element_by_xpath(xpaths['submitButton']).click()
```

I run this, and selenium opens coinbase, then refreshes after a couple seconds, then nothing happens.

Comment: Are you sure your xpaths are hitting the right elements? For the two `send_keys` you should see the text typed in at least. If the xpaths are off but *still* match something, Selenium will happily go forth sending keys and clicking on the wrong elements.

Answer (score 4):

You are specifying:

```
xpaths['usernameTxtBox']
```

but it doesn't exist according to your array:

```
xpaths = {
'usernameTxtBox' # needs to be in the array
'emailTxtBox' : '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div/input',      
'passwordTxtBox' : '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[3]/div/input',
'submitButton' : '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[4]/div/input'
    }
```

**Edit after comment:**
I'd consider either revising your xpath, or Keeping It Simple, (Stupid).

```
//input[@id='email']
//input[@id='password']
//input[@id='signin_button']
```

Comment: That was just a typo in in the post, sorry. it still wont work.

Comment: I fixed my answer. I was suppost to be using browser. instead of mydriver. Silly me. Thanks anyways for trying to help