# Selenium Web driver Installation

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, spyder

Someone please help with the steps to install selenium web driver in python. I am using spyder - python 2.7 for my project and I am little new to python.

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python

Comment: try `easy_install selenium` in cli.

Comment: after using above command an error is occuring: no local packages or download link found for selenium. error: coul not find suitable distribution for Requirement

Comment: try Download the `wheel` from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium#downloads) and `install` it using `pip install filename`

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in your cli:

`pip install -U selenium`

Comment: its showing no matching distribution found for selenium

Answer (score -1):

Download selenium-version.tar.gz
run python setup.py install