# How do you use the beautiful soup module to click a link on a webpage repeatedly?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have a group of year 9 girls who have entered a national competition.  One of their tasks is to find the token that is displayed after they have clicked on a link 1,000,000 times.  The webpage is simple - it has one button on it.  I am sure that we can write some code to do this for us - I have heard of the Beautiful soup thing - does anyone have instructions how to do this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup is a package for parsing HTML, i.e., retrieving elements or text from a request. You want something that simulates interacting with a web browser. [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17540971/7376) is a good choice for this and works with Python.