# Using Selenium with Python on LinkedIn

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, bots, linkedin-api

I am in the process of building a script using python and selenium which clicks on the 'message button' on my network to send a default message.

Linkedin uses dynamic fields (ember), so it's not possible to find elements by id. So far I have tried:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("...").click()
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("button").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("...").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(//...)
```

This is my code so far:

```
def TextBot(browser):
time.sleep(3)
browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/')
time.sleep(3)
xpath = '//button[contains(@aria-label,"Send message to")]'
time.sleep(3)
buttons = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
for btn in buttons:
    print("Can %s" % btn.get_attribute("aria-label"))  

def Main():
#Parse enail and password to the script
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('email', help='linkedin email')
parser.add_argument('password', help='linkedin password')
args = parser.parse_args()

#browse to the login page
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://linkedin.com/uas/login')

#Parse the two argument in the login form
emailElement = browser.find_element_by_id('session_key-login')
emailElement.send_keys(args.email)
passElement = browser.find_element_by_id('session_password-login')
passElement.send_keys(args.password)
passElement.submit()

#Initialise ViewBot function
os.system('clear') #cls rather than clear on windows
print ("[+] Success! Logged In, Bot Starting")
#ViewBot(browser)
TextBot(browser)
browser.close()
```

And my error:

> File "LinkedInBot.py", line 88, in TextBot
>       buttons = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 393, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 966, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
>   line 320, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
>   line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to
>   locate element: //button[contains(@aria-label,"Send message to")]

Is there anything else I am not thinking about?

By the way thanks for the answers so far. I am close but I still think there is some other form of encryption to bypass

Comment: Share code you're using with locators, steps and try add waits

Comment: Cheers! I added waits all over the place. If I type: page.find_all('button') the I get a list, but when I do it via driver.find_element_by I always get ths error above

Comment: I gave you code you need below in my answer

Comment: Thank you mate! Any idea why I get: name 'By' is not defined error? Any imports apart fromm yours i missed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python

Comment: Now I get this error:
connectionsHeader = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".message-anywhere-button"))).text
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", l
ine 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

The message is empty but I changed the time from 20 to 3 to 10. I guess the real problem is it cannot find the element by css selector...

Answer (score 2):

"Message button" in Linkedin looks like this:

```
<button class="message-anywhere-button mn-connection-card__message-btn button-secondary-medium" aria-label="Send message to John Smith" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-5128="5128">
  <span aria-hidden="true">Message</span>
  <span class="visually-hidden">
    Send a message to John Smith
  </span>
</button>
```

So for locator you have several options, lets settle on most primitive one: look for `Send message to` text inside `aria-label`:

```
xpath = '//button[contains(@aria-label,"Send message to")]'
```

This locator will find *all* buttons. But depending on which function you call, you may end up choosing only first element, or all elements. Lets say the goal is to collect all the buttons:

```
xpath = '//button[contains(@aria-label,"Send message to")]'
all_message_buttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, xpath)
for message_button in all_message_buttons:
    print("Can %s" % message_button.get_attribute("aria-label")) 
    # prints Can Send Message to John Smith
    # and any other names available on page
```

Finally, before selecting buttons you need to make sure that page was loaded and buttons are indeed displayed. There are various ways to do that, but I usually just replace finding elements I need with waiting for them:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# ...
xpath = '//button[contains(@aria-label,"Send message to")]'
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10) # wait for up to 10 sec
all_message_buttons = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
for message_button in all_message_buttons:
    print("Can %s" % message_button.get_attribute("aria-label")) 
    # prints Can Send Message to John Smith
    # and any other names available on page
```

Answer (score 2):

Code below scroll down until all contacts have been loaded.
Then get all message buttons, click, send and close message window.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re

#...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
connectionsHeader = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mn-connections__header h2"))).text
totalConnections = int(re.findall(r"\d+", connectionsHeader))
while len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mn-connections li")) < totalConnections-1:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 100);")

messageButtons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".mn-connections li button.mn-connection-card__message-btn")

for button in messageButtons:
    button.click()
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".msg-form__contenteditable"))).click()
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".msg-form__contenteditable").send_keys('message')
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".js-msg-close").click()
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".js-msg-close")))
```

Not: *code may contains typos or small errors. Feel free to improve it*.

Comment: Yes I did. Got the following error now
error: connectionsHeader = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".message-anywhere-button"))).text File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", l ine 80, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 

The message is empty but I changed the time from 20 to 3 to 10. I guess the real problem is it cannot find the element by css selector...

Comment: Check again, I used `.mn-connections__header h2` not `.message-anywhere-button`

Comment: Yes, I tried with both your classes and the classes I found on the page I am in, but no success. Always Timeout Error. time.sleep() doesn't throw that error but I still get the same proble later on of no element been found. No idea how to get out of it...

Comment: You didn't even try. There were huge mistake you could not run it.