# Python & BeautifulSoup 4 - Unable to get Newegg prices?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape Newegg product pages for prices and I always seem to be running into the same problem - the result is always 'None'.

Here's a few very basic lines of code that work for similar sites such as Amazon:

```
 data = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824475015&cm_sp=Homepage_Dailydeal-_-P1_24-475-015-_-03042019')
 soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')
 price = soup.find('li', class_='price-current').text.strip()
```

I'm expecting to get $419.99 as the output, but instead I get None.

When I try to get the product title, I get the desired result. It's only the prices that are giving me this issue. Has anyone had the same issue and how can this be fixed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The web page you're parsing appears to have some dynamically generated content. Try [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python)

Comment: I have tried Selenium and some other things which I was unable to get to work, that's why I had to ask for help. I prefer figuring things out on my own but I was just stuck on this one. I appreciate the quick replies and all the help I got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an attribute selector to target an element containing that price in its content attribute.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = requests.get('https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824475015&cm_sp=Homepage_Dailydeal-_-P1_24-475-015-_-03042019')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content, 'lxml')
price = soup.select_one('[itemprop=price]')['content']
print(price)
```

Comment: FWIW, while still display the correct price, this searches for a different tag than the OP is looking for. Mostly due to the fact the web page the OP is scraping is dynamically generated. Still +1 though

Comment: @Wondercricket. Thanks. Yup. That is why I went for that.

Comment: Simple and gets the job done; just what I needed for this task. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the lxml Library as shown below. With it you can use XPATH which is great.

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

url =  "URL HERE"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(response, htmlparser)
tree.xpath('//*[@id="newproductversion"]/span/strong')
```

I get the expected output 
419.99

Comment: This will come in very handy with something else I'm planning to do, I appreciate it very much.