# ImportError: No module named selenium using import selenium even after installing Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pip, webdriver

I am trying to run tests with selenium in python, but it can not be recognized.

I have tried uninstalling with `pip uninstall selenium` and reinstalling, and it has not worked.

When i run `import selenium` i get this error:

```
import selenium
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named selenium
```

But, when I run `pip install selenium`, I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.9)
```

I am not sure if Selenium is just in the wrong place on my machine so it can not be recognized, or what is going on.

Thanks

Comment: Check if `python --version` with which you run the code is also 3.7

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of reasons this may fail. The easiest to validate is if it is available in the environment you are working?

Check by running `pip list` from terminal while in the environment you are running your python module or notebook from.

Can you say if you’re using a venv?

Also, I think you typically
`from selenium import webdriver`
not selenium alone.

[Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
import selenium 

Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in ImportError: No module named selenium
```

...implies that there was an error while invoking the *Selenium* module.

---

### Analysis

On executing the line of code:

```
pip install selenium
```

As you are seeing the message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.9)
```

implies that [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) is already installed in your system.

---

### Solution

Presumably, instead of using:

```
import selenium
```

You need to use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Python : no module named selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48267633/python-no-module-named-selenium/48269228#48269228)