# How can I log in to my Facebook from python program without getting locked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook

I am trying to send messages to Facebook friends via Messenger. I found a tutorial & tried it.

```
import fbchat 
from getpass import getpass 
username = str(raw_input("Username: ")) 
client = fbchat.Client(username, getpass()) 
no_of_friends = int(raw_input("Number of friends: ")) 
for i in xrange(no_of_friends): 
    name = str(raw_input("Name: ")) 
    friends = client.getUsers(name) # return a list of names 
    friend = friends[0] 
    msg = str(raw_input("Message: ")) 
    sent = client.send(friend.uid, msg) 
    if sent: 
        print("Message sent successfully!")
```

When I ran the program, it requested me my password. And, of course, I entered it. But Facebook doesn't accept the request from my program & lock my Facebook account. I think this is due to security reasons. Then how can I log in to my Facebook from python program without getting locked? Thanks.

Comment: _“Then how can I log in to my Facebook from python program without getting locked?”_ - you’re not supposed to do that at all. _“I am trying to send messages to Facebook friends via Messenger.”_ - use the web UI, or one of the native apps then …? Why would there be any reason to try and “automate” this using external tools in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like the issue lies with your library, not with you. You should make a new issue at their github page. https://github.com/carpedm20/fbchat

You can [selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python) to remotely control the browser and do stuff a normal user can do, including logging into facebook.