# How to define driver in pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I'm new to python selenium tests and, after Java C#  projects,  I'm a little bit confused.
Before I set up a driver I need to define it with some Type, for example in Java:

```
static WebDriver driver;
if ('Chrome') {
    driver = ...
} else {
    driver = ...
}
```

How can I define driver in python and how other classes can access it without driver instance creation? Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the documentation here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/getting_started/open_browser/

Comment: Thanks for your reply,  but I still don't understand how can I define a cross-browser driver...(as in the question) in python it can't be static. In the start I want it to be None and after this, I define it as Chrome or FF, etc. And because the driver is not static I can't understand how other classes can access it. Thanks

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python

Comment: You can use a member variable that is initialized in the constructor. Or you can wrap the WebDriver with your own wrapper classes for different browsers. There is a multitude of solutions and it depends on what else you want to do, to know which solution is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works the same in python as it does in Java/C#. Once you have your `driver` variable instantiated with the desired browser, you just pass the `driver` instance to a new class/page object.

Your test would look like

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome() # or whatever browser driver you want
driver.get("https://www.website.com")
...
homePage = HomePage(driver)
assert homePage.get_username() == "John Smith"
```

and then you define your HomePage class

```
class HomePage()
    USERNAME_LOCATOR = (By.ID, 'username')

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def get_username(self):
        return self.driver.find_element(USERNAME_LOCATOR).text
```