# How to send text to input field using Selenium/Python?

Tags: html

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="none" data-test="check-email-availability-email-input" formcontrolname="alias" class="pos-form-element pos-text-input email-alias-input__alias-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched">
```

The above is the html element for an input box (https://signup.mail.com/#.7518-header-signup1-1). How can I input text inside the box? What would the code look like? I'm new to automation using Selenium, so seeing the code for this would be very helpful. driver.find_element() is the only way that works programmatically. find_element_by_xpath, etc. doesn't work, and I'm assuming that's due to the methods being outdated.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540971/how-to-use-selenium-with-python

Comment: you can look at the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) and if you have bump into any issues with the code you write, then update the question to include the code you were trying to use and the error you bump into and what was the expected result